# Android : APK generated in Gradle not replacing APK generated from native android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I just moved my native android application to gradle. Now if i generate the signed APK using same signature that i used for native.I get a different application in my phone. (it's not replacing the old one - native APK) So i see 2 applications with same name. I checked and the package name hasn't changed. What could be causing this ?

Any suggestions ? Or is it something i need to deal with since i migrated to gradle. Any input will be very helpful.

edit 1 : Thanks for all your replies. I am adding my **old Intellij IDEA** build manifest and new **Android Studio Gradle Build file**. Please check and let me know what changes i need to do.

[image: New Android Studio Gradle Build]

The old intellij idea manifest is :

[image: Old intellij idea manifest]

Comment: Check your gradle file for ```applicationId``` value or ```applicationSuffix```. These can change the package name of your app. It would also help if you post your gradle file.

Comment: For some reason, the applicationId (old package name) of those versions are different... that's why you see two apps... Check your build.gradle to ensure that in the end, you will generate an app with same package name (applicationId)

Comment: Or share your manifest.xml (from native version) and the build.gradle file from current version

Comment: @GuilhermeP : I have added the images. Please check them out

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.gradle, defaultConfig, productFlavors and buildTypes.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename